# MySQL SELECT ... FOR UPDATE

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking, row

I'm trying to execute this query.

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE id = 11 FOR UPDATE;
COMMIT;
```

I want to lock only the row with id = 11 but MySQL give me this error:

`1064 - SQL query syntax error near 'LIMIT 0, 25' line 1`

My table (InnoDB) is composed as follows:

[image: table]

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you please try giving more information about your problem and edit your question accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE id = 11;
```

if you want to update then run update query

```
update calender set field1=value1,field2=value2 where id =11;
```

Comment: Hi, i have do implement a booking system so i have to refer to trasnaction system of mysql.  don't know if your querys it won't suit me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).